# sql server- Creating stored procedure failed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I am working on a program in c# that involves calling a stored procedure in sql server to create tables. The issue is I cannot create the procedure in SQL server as it keep giving me syntax error, I double checked and can't seem to find anything wrong with it.

The error stated is incorrect syntax near 'TRY' and near 'Catch' .I know the code is bit long but I think it's better to post it as a whole.

The stored procedure is supposed to execute this by calling the sql server to create the table.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author: Nicholas
-- Create date: 11/01/2017
-- Description: Creating new tables for data archiving.
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateTables

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
         --use transaction when inserting data else you may end up with orphaned data and hard to debug issues later on
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        --add your CREATE queries one after the other below

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]    Script Date: 03/10/2017 2:29:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New](
    [EventCode] [varchar](8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [ChDescription] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [AdditionalInfo] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ChAdditionalInfo] [nvarchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [EventTypeCode] [varchar](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [CategoryId] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [BenefitSelection] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [NoOfBenefitSelection] [int] NULL,
    [LimitedVoucherAllotment] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [SplitAllotment] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [LimitedPermission] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [AttachMemberID] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [DRSPreferenceFlag] [varchar](4) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [PreferenceValue] [varchar](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [LimitedRedemption] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [MaxRedemptionQty] [int] NULL,
    [QtyPerRedemption] [int] NULL,
    [RedemptionPeriod] [int] NULL,
    [PeriodType] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [CalendarDate] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [CreateBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [char](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CancelReason] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [DailyAllotment] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [LastChangeBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [LastChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ImageFile] [image] NULL,
    [RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [ImageFileName] [varchar](200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [DRSReport] [varchar](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [CXLParameterCode] [varchar](8) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [CRMCode] [varchar](36) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [NonCRMProfile] [char](2) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [OTTarget] [bit] NULL,
    [evsProgID] [varchar](10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PromotionEvent_New] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EventCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] TO  SCHEMA OWNER 
GO

GRANT DELETE ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] TO [APPRole] AS [dbo]
GO

GRANT INSERT ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] TO [APPRole] AS [dbo]
GO

GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] TO [APPRole] AS [dbo]
GO

GRANT UPDATE ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] TO [APPRole] AS [dbo]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [_dta_index_PromotionEvent_18_1013578649__K6_K1_K28_K7_K8_New]    Script Date: 03/10/2017 2:29:57 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]') AND name = N'_dta_index_PromotionEvent_18_1013578649__K6_K1_K28_K7_K8_New')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_PromotionEvent_18_1013578649__K6_K1_K28_K7_K8_New] ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]
(
    [EventTypeCode] ASC,
    [EventCode] ASC,
    [Status] ASC,
    [StartDate] ASC,
    [EndDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [idx_PromotionEvent_3_New]    Script Date: 03/10/2017 2:29:57 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]') AND name = N'idx_PromotionEvent_3_New')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_PromotionEvent_3_New] ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]
(
    [StartDate] ASC,
    [EndDate] ASC,
    [StartTime] ASC,
    [EndTime] ASC,
    [LimitedVoucherAllotment] ASC,
    [LimitedPermission] ASC,
    [AttachMemberID] ASC,
    [Status] ASC,
    [DailyAllotment] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_PromotionEvent_1_New]    Script Date: 03/10/2017 2:29:57 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]') AND name = N'IX_PromotionEvent_1_New')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PromotionEvent_1_New] ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]
(
    [StartDate] ASC,
    [EndDate] ASC,
    [Status] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF_PromotionEvent_DRSPreferenceFlag_New]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PromotionEvent_DRSPreferenceFlag_New]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [DRSPreferenceFlag]
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF_PromotionEvent_PreferenceValue_New]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PromotionEvent_PreferenceValue_New]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [PreferenceValue]
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF_PromotionEvent_QtyPerRedemption_New]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PromotionEvent_QtyPerRedemption_New]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [QtyPerRedemption]
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF_PromotionEvent_RedemptionPeriod_New]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PromotionEvent_RedemptionPeriod_New]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [RedemptionPeriod]
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF__Promotion__OTTar__6DA491D6_New]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Promotion__OTTar__6DA491D6_New]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [OTTarget]
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF__Promotion__evsPr__6E98B60F_New]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Promotion__evsPr__6E98B60F_New]  DEFAULT ('GCVS_Promo') FOR [evsProgID]
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_PromotionEvent_EventCategory_New]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PromotionEvent_EventCategory_New] FOREIGN KEY([CategoryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[EventCategory] ([CategoryId])
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_PromotionEvent_EventCategory_New]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PromotionEvent_EventCategory_New]
GO



/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tg_D_PROMOTIONEVENT_New]    Script Date: 03/10/2017 2:29:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tg_D_PROMOTIONEVENT_New]'))
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE     TRIGGER [dbo].[tg_D_PROMOTIONEVENT_New] ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] FOR  DELETE AS 
 INSERT INTO AUDITPROMOTIONEVENT( [AuditType], [EventCode], [Description], [ChDescription], 
[AdditionalInfo], [ChAdditionalInfo], [EventTypeCode], [StartDate], [EndDate], 
[StartTime], [EndTime], [CategoryId], [BenefitSelection], [NoOfBenefitSelection], 
[LimitedVoucherAllotment], [SplitAllotment], [LimitedPermission], [AttachMemberID], 
[DRSPreferenceFlag], [PreferenceValue], [LimitedRedemption], [MaxRedemptionQty], [QtyPerRedemption], 
[RedemptionPeriod], [PeriodType], [CalendarDate], [CreateBy], [CreateDate], [Status], [CancelReason], 
[LastChangeBy], [LastChangeDate], [CRMCode],[NonCRMProfile] )
 SELECT ''D'' ,rec.[EventCode], rec.[Description], rec.[ChDescription], 
rec.[AdditionalInfo], rec.[ChAdditionalInfo], rec.[EventTypeCode], rec.[StartDate], rec.[EndDate], 
rec.[StartTime], rec.[EndTime], rec.[CategoryId], rec.[BenefitSelection], rec.[NoOfBenefitSelection], 
rec.[LimitedVoucherAllotment], rec.[SplitAllotment], rec.[LimitedPermission], rec.[AttachMemberID], 
rec.[DRSPreferenceFlag], rec.[PreferenceValue], rec.[LimitedRedemption], rec.[MaxRedemptionQty], rec.[QtyPerRedemption], 
rec.[RedemptionPeriod], rec.[PeriodType], rec.[CalendarDate], rec.[CreateBy], rec.[CreateDate], rec.[Status], rec.[CancelReason], 
rec.[LastChangeBy], rec.[LastChangeDate], rec.[CRMCode],rec.[NonCRMProfile]
from deleted rec' 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] ENABLE TRIGGER [tg_D_PROMOTIONEVENT_New]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tg_I_PROMOTIONEVENT_New]    Script Date: 03/10/2017 2:29:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tg_I_PROMOTIONEVENT_New]'))
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE    TRIGGER [dbo].[tg_I_PROMOTIONEVENT_New] ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] FOR  INSERT AS 
 INSERT INTO AUDITPROMOTIONEVENT( [AuditType], [EventCode], [Description], [ChDescription], 
[AdditionalInfo], [ChAdditionalInfo], [EventTypeCode], [StartDate], [EndDate], 
[StartTime], [EndTime], [CategoryId], [BenefitSelection], [NoOfBenefitSelection], 
[LimitedVoucherAllotment], [SplitAllotment], [LimitedPermission], [AttachMemberID], 
[DRSPreferenceFlag], [PreferenceValue], [LimitedRedemption], [MaxRedemptionQty], [QtyPerRedemption], 
[RedemptionPeriod], [PeriodType], [CalendarDate], [CreateBy], [CreateDate], [Status], [CancelReason], 
[LastChangeBy], [LastChangeDate], [CRMCode],[NonCRMProfile] )
 SELECT ''I'' , rec.[EventCode], rec.[Description], rec.[ChDescription], 
rec.[AdditionalInfo], rec.[ChAdditionalInfo], rec.[EventTypeCode], rec.[StartDate], rec.[EndDate], 
rec.[StartTime], rec.[EndTime], rec.[CategoryId], rec.[BenefitSelection], rec.[NoOfBenefitSelection], 
rec.[LimitedVoucherAllotment], rec.[SplitAllotment], rec.[LimitedPermission], rec.[AttachMemberID], 
rec.[DRSPreferenceFlag], rec.[PreferenceValue], rec.[LimitedRedemption], rec.[MaxRedemptionQty], rec.[QtyPerRedemption], 
rec.[RedemptionPeriod], rec.[PeriodType], rec.[CalendarDate], rec.[CreateBy], rec.[CreateDate], rec.[Status], rec.[CancelReason], 
rec.[LastChangeBy], rec.[LastChangeDate], rec.[CRMCode],rec.[NonCRMProfile]
from inserted rec' 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] ENABLE TRIGGER [tg_I_PROMOTIONEVENT_New]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tg_U_PROMOTIONEVENT_New]    Script Date: 03/10/2017 2:29:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tg_U_PROMOTIONEVENT_New]'))
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE     TRIGGER [dbo].[tg_U_PROMOTIONEVENT_New] ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New]  FOR  UPDATE AS 
 INSERT INTO AUDITPROMOTIONEVENT
([AuditType], [EventCode], [Description], [ChDescription], 
[AdditionalInfo], [ChAdditionalInfo], [EventTypeCode], [StartDate], [EndDate], 
[StartTime], [EndTime], [CategoryId], [BenefitSelection], [NoOfBenefitSelection], 
[LimitedVoucherAllotment], [SplitAllotment], [LimitedPermission], [AttachMemberID], 
[DRSPreferenceFlag], [PreferenceValue], [LimitedRedemption], [MaxRedemptionQty], [QtyPerRedemption], 
[RedemptionPeriod], [PeriodType], [CalendarDate], [CreateBy], [CreateDate], [Status], [CancelReason], 
[LastChangeBy], [LastChangeDate], [CRMCode],[NonCRMProfile] )
 SELECT ''U'' , rec.[EventCode], rec.[Description], rec.[ChDescription], 
rec.[AdditionalInfo], rec.[ChAdditionalInfo], rec.[EventTypeCode], rec.[StartDate], rec.[EndDate], 
rec.[StartTime], rec.[EndTime], rec.[CategoryId], rec.[BenefitSelection], rec.[NoOfBenefitSelection], 
rec.[LimitedVoucherAllotment], rec.[SplitAllotment], rec.[LimitedPermission], rec.[AttachMemberID], 
rec.[DRSPreferenceFlag], rec.[PreferenceValue], rec.[LimitedRedemption], rec.[MaxRedemptionQty], rec.[QtyPerRedemption], 
rec.[RedemptionPeriod], rec.[PeriodType], rec.[CalendarDate], rec.[CreateBy], rec.[CreateDate], rec.[Status], rec.[CancelReason], 
rec.[LastChangeBy], rec.[LastChangeDate], rec.[CRMCode],rec.[NonCRMProfile]
from deleted rec' 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PromotionEvent_New] ENABLE TRIGGER [tg_U_PROMOTIONEVENT_New]
END


        --add more of your create tables queries below


        -- finally commit transaction
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @errorDetails NVARCHAR(MAX);
        set @errorDetails = 'Error ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ERROR_NUMBER()) +
        ', Severity ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), ERROR_SEVERITY()) +
        ', State ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), ERROR_STATE()) +
        ', Line ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), ERROR_LINE());

          --roll back the transaction
        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

        --you can log the above error message and/or re-throw the error so your C# code will see an error
        --but do this only after rolling back
    END CATCH;
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you please show your `try/catch` part in c#?

Comment: Why would you need the c# code? All I am doing is creating a stored procedure inside SSMS. The c# part is just for me to execute by calling the stored procedure in SSMS.

Comment: Oh, I see you've removed `c#` tag..

Comment: Yup, it was my bad.

Comment: I suggest breaking this massive procedure to smaller ones, each responsible to a single table. Once you have done that, it's going to be much easier to maintain, and you won't have to deal with such a massive code to find the errors.

Comment: It's basically just syntax errors like near 'TRY' and 'catch'. Is my format for creating sp correct first of all?

Comment: Zohar, but this stored procedure is just for one table, because i want to create constraints,triggers,indexes,etc as well that's why it 's long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send
>   the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements
>   entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc session or
>   script if this is the first GO. +

Comment: Emmmmmm... So?.

Comment: What's the solution to this?

Comment: Dont use GO inside CREATE PROC

Comment: @TapakahUa add your suggestion/solution to your answer.

Comment: Solution: completely rewrite its procedure

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use GO inside the stored procedure, function or trigger.
Usually, GO terminates the procedure declaration.